# Collecting coordinates of Twitter in Python package

Tags: python, twitter

I try to collect data from twitter with coordinates. However, I got the results is`'coordinates: None'`

```
from twitter import *
from email.utils import parsedate

stream = TwitterStream(auth = auth, secure = True)
stream

search_term = "candy"
tweet_stream = stream.statuses.filter(track = search_term, language='en',    geo=True) 

l =[]

for tweet in tweet_stream:
    l.append(tweet)
```

Do we have a parameters to collect the geo-data from twitter? Or it depends on the users with permission to access the location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few users are intentionnaly sharing their location.
I heard about 1%. It can't be set by default due to privacy rights.

You can get coordinates like this :

```
if tweet.coordinates is not None:
    #print(tweet.coordinates) # => {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [2.28892949, 48.85200032]}
    lon = tweet.coordinates['coordinates'][0]
    lat = tweet.coordinates['coordinates'][1]
```